# Store total sales of a product per customer role

Tags: woocommerce

In WooCommerce every product has a field 'total_sales'. However, I have two different customers:

1. Retail customers: guest checkout or customer role 'customer'.
2. Wholesale customers: user role 'wholesale_customer'.

I would like to add two extra fields to every products:

1. total_sales_retail
2. total_sales_wholesale

I can manage to add those fields to the products, but how to get the data in there, if this is possible?